# Pick the last date within 1 year of the min date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to create a new column that returns the last date within 1 year of the first date.

Example:

I have the following dates.

```
5/6/2011
8/9/2011
3/5/2012
6/8/2012
```

So the query should pick 3/5/2012 as the last date in this scenario.

Comment: Please update your question and include your best attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Pet peeve:  Ambiguous dates in sample data.  Is this M/D/Y or D/M/Y  ?

Comment: What is the datatype of your column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select max(dt)
from (select t.*, min(dt) over () as min_dt
      from t
     ) t
where dt < dateadd(year, 1, min_dt);
```

I think I prefer a correlated subquery, though:

```
select max(dt)
from t
where dt < (select dateadd(year, 1, min(dt)) from t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much translate your English spec into an sql for this one:

```
 SELECT max(d) 
 FROM  t
 WHERE d < (SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, MIN(d)) FROM t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your column name is `dt` and your table name is `Tbl`

```
SELECT MAX(dt)
FROM Tbl
WHERE dt < (SELECT MIN(dt) + 365 FROM Tbl)
```